# Fourier Series of a piecewise function

Tags: continuous-signals, homework, fourier, fourier-series, periodic

I've been given the task to find the Fourier Series Representation. All I'm given is this $$x(t)= \begin{cases}-t & \text { for } 0 \leq t<1 \\ 1 & \text { for } 1 \leq t<2 \\ 0 & \text { for } 2 \leq t<4\end{cases}$$
and I have no idea as to how to go about it. In the lectures we were shown $$
x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_{k} e^{j k \omega_{0} t}
$$ and $$
a_{k}=\frac{1}{T} \int_{T} x(t) e^{-j k \omega_{0} t} d t
$$ but I simply do not understand what they mean or how to use them on the given $x(t)$. My confusion mainly comes from the fact that I need $x(t)$ in the calculation of $a_k$, but I don't see how that's possible with the given. I might also be on the entirely wrong track. Please help me.

EDIT: The period is given as $T=4$. Pardon for the exclusion.

Comment: This problem seems incomplete. What  is $x(t)$ outside the interval [0,4] ? Is it zero or is there periodic repetition? The use of the  Fourier Series would imply that it is periodic but that should be stated somewhere explicitly. Step 1: draw x(t) on a piece of paper.

Comment: @Hilmar I believe the Fourier Series can also be applied to any time limited analytic function such as from $0$ to $T$, and then implied periodic over that interval if you extend beyond that. Basically saying if we have a function defined from $0$ to $T$, we can use the FSE to describe that function over that interval as an infinite sum of sines and cosines over that same interval.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [piecewise function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise), you need to separate the integral over that function into the same number of (sub-)intervals:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^4x(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt&=\int_0^1x(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt+\int_1^2x(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt+\int_2^4x(t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt\\&=\int_0^1(-t)e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt+\int_1^2e^{-jk\omega_0t}dt\end{align}$$

with $\omega_0=2\pi/T=\pi/2$.

I trust that you can take it from here.

Comment: and importantly $\omega_0$ is given by the total time duration as  $\omega_0 = 1/(2\pi 4)$

Comment: @DanBoschen: Thanks for the addition, I'll add it to my answer. But it should be $\omega_0=2\pi /T=2\pi /4=\pi/2$.

Comment: yes - of course!  (I figured that might have been the sticking point)

Comment: I really wish I could take it from there, but I won't pester you lot with more of my stupidity. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @ian: So what exactly is the problem? You don't know how to integrate those functions?

Comment: Just about everything embarrasingly... What to do from there. What the result is actually suppose to look like. I'm just lost at this course..

Comment: @ian: I've been where you are and not that long ago. If you want to understand fourier series ( don't even think about FT, DFT, DTFT. Thinking about them, for me, confused the issue even more ), I highly recommend George Tolstov's "Fourier Series". Go over all the examples carefully.  Then, once you got that down,  you can work on the other ones ( FT, DFT, DTFT ) where the functions aren't as "nice" or the assumptions are different. Also, stay on this site and listen. There are many smart, patient  and generous people who really know how to explain things.